# How do I get unique values within a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to get a list of unique values that occur within a cell

For example,

**Cell A1:**

```
apple 
orange 
apple
```

**Expected Result in Cell B1:**

```
apple
orange
```

Second Example,

**Cell A1:**

```
KB4454509
17.0.10737.12110
KB4494506
17.0.10737.12110
```

**Expected Result in Cell B1:**

```
KB4454509
17.0.10737.12110
KB4494506
```

**Tried:**

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,RegExpExtract(A1,$C$1))
```

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "))))`?

Comment: @BigBen Instead of `TOCOL`, use the 2nd argument of `UNIQUE` i.e. `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),1))` or the 3rd argument of `TEXTSPLIT` i.e. `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,," ")))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do it once in a while, use the "Advance filter" under "Data"->"Sort & Filter" section.  (select "Copy to another location" option and the "Unique Record Only" checkbox)

I personally prefer to use PivotTable, use the item list as Rows.